# Numpy: find occurrences for non-zero values, grouped by index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a collection of 3D arrays, each of which represents an image. I want to find the number of occurrences where a given coordinate contains a non-black pixel across all arrays.

```
result = np.zeros_like(list_of_arrays[0])
for array in list_of_arrays:
    for (y, x) in np.argwhere(array.any(-1)):
        result[y][x] += 1
return result
```

How can I best improve on this naïve implementation? If I knew how to convert the 3rd dimension to either a 0 or 1, I could copy each array then add them to get my answer. The problem is I don't know how to do that conversion.

---

Example for two 3x3 pictures

```
# picture 1
[[[ 208.,  208.,  208.],
  [   0.,    0.,    0.],
  [ 110.,  110.,  110.]],

 [[ 161.,  161.,  161.],
  [ 140.,  140.,  140.],
  [ 251.,  251.,  251.]],

 [[   0.,    0.,    0.],
  [  55.,   55.,   55.],
  [  26.,   26.,   26.]]]

# picture 2
[[[  88.,   88.,   88.],
  [ 140.,  140.,  140.],
  [   0.,    0.,    0.]],

 [[  18.,   18.,   18.],
  [ 112.,  112.,  112.],
  [   0.,    0.,    0.]],

 [[   0.,    0.,    0.],
  [ 195.,  195.,  195.],
  [   5.,    5.,    5.]]]

# what I'd like
[[[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
  [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
  [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

 [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
  [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
  [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

 [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
  [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
  [ 2.,  2.,  2.]]]
```

Comment: Could you show a (very small) example input, e.g. for a 5x5 pixel image?

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that from the start. Done.

Comment: Do you have those pictures stored in a single array or separate ones? If single, how are they stored? `4D` array or list of 3D arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since black is represented by `0`, you could convert the arrays to boolean by using `array.astype('bool')` so that black becomes `False` and every other color becomes `True`. Combining those arrays with `sum` will convert them back to integer, while `True` is turned into `1` so that you end up with the number of non-black pixels at each coordinate:

```
result = sum(ar.astype('bool') for ar in list_of_arrays)
```

As an alternative to data type conversion, you could use `numpy.minimum` to threshold the images:

```
result = sum(np.minimum(ar, 1) for ar in list_of_arrays)
```

---

**Edit:** For the case that speed matters, I've conducted a litte benchmark comparing the above two approaches with that of ohruunuruus:

```
>>> ar = [np.array([[ 208.,  208.,  208.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 110.,  110.,  110.]]), np.array([[ 161.,  161.,  161.],
       [ 140.,  140.,  140.],
       [ 251.,  251.,  251.]]), np.array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 55.,  55.,  55.],
       [ 26.,  26.,  26.]])]

>>> from time import time
>>> def f1(arrays):
...     return sum(np.minimum(a, 1) for a in arrays)
...
>>> def f2(arrays):
...     return sum(a.astype('bool') for a in arrays)
...
>>> def f3(arrays):
...     return (np.array(arrays) != 0).sum(axis=0)
...
>>> def timeIt(func):
...     start = time()
...     for i in range(1000000):
...         func(ar)
...     stop = time()
...     return stop-start
...

>>> timeIt(f1)
12.203268051147461
>>> timeIt(f2)
16.594016790390015
>>> timeIt(f3)
18.328339099884033
```

Results may vary with different numbers and sizes of images.

Comment: Good point: if the pictures are already stored in a list, then your list comprehension approaches are faster (do they require one less traversal?). That said, if the images are _already_ stored in a numpy array then just using sum along `axis=0` is faster. If OP has a choice of data structure when initially creating the collection of photographs, and chooses a numpy array instead of a list, I think my approach is more performant.

Comment: You're right @ohruunuruus. I guess, casting the list to `np.array` involves expensive copying of the data. But if one is in control of how the images are stored, I would prefer the `np.sum` approach too.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose those two images are numpy arrays called `pic1` and `pic2`:

```
pic1 = np.array(
    [[[ 208.,  208.,  208.],
      [   0.,    0.,    0.],
      [ 110.,  110.,  110.]],

     [[ 161.,  161.,  161.],
      [ 140.,  140.,  140.],
      [ 251.,  251.,  251.]],

     [[   0.,    0.,    0.],
      [  55.,   55.,   55.],
      [  26.,   26.,   26.]]]
)

pic2 = np.array(
    [[[  88.,   88.,   88.],
      [ 140.,  140.,  140.],
      [   0.,    0.,    0.]],

     [[  18.,   18.,   18.],
      [ 112.,  112.,  112.],
      [   0.,    0.,    0.]],

     [[   0.,    0.,    0.],
      [ 195.,  195.,  195.],
      [   5.,    5.,    5.]]]
)
```

You can create a numpy array of these images with `np.array([pic1, pic2])` or if you already have the images in a list then `np.array(list_of_arrays)`. Then, apply a logical operation to this four dimensional array to each element individually, checking if each is nonzero. Finally, sum the resulting four dimensional array specifying `axis=0`:

```
# Get a numpy array of images
images = np.array([pic1, pic2]) # or np.array(list_of_arrays)

# Check for nonzero values and sum along the relevant axis
result = (images != 0).sum(axis=0)

array([[[2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
```

If the images are already in a list, then this approach may not be as fast as others. That said, if you have a choice of data structure when first creating your collection of images, and can use a numpy array, this is fastest.